# Регулярное выражение. Превращение ссылок в гиперссылки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url

Надо превращать все вставленные ссылки в гиперссылки (как ВК).

Не могу найти подходящий regexp, после ссылки может быть сразу точка, скобка, ещё чего, что юзер придумает. То, что я находил, захватывало эти символы за компанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача практически невыполнимая, так как по спецификации в URL могут быть самые разнообразные символы, и достоверно отличить, где URL, а где текст, невозможно.

Тем не менее, как вариант:

```
/((?:(?:https?):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:;,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:;,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:;,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]))/ig
```

DEMO: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddencr5t/)**

Comment: Спасибо, мне этого достаточно)

Пока искал решение, натолкнулся на сайт, может кому поможет https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex